# Google Maps - common case pricing confusion

Tags: android, google-maps

Currently, I have Place Autocomplete implemented inside my Android app (https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete to be more specific I used "Option 2: Use an intent to launch the autocomplete activity"). I am really confused about current Google Maps pricing and I wonder, which row at this table concerns me: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/. All I need is to enable user to enter a (partial) location name, show some suggestions (they don't have to be displayed dynamically - I can show some suggestions even after user presses "enter") and after user selects one of the options all I need is coordinates and displayed name. Could you help me address those two issues and find the most affordable option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of Places SDK for Android doesn't fit the new pricing model. As far as I know at the moment Places SDK for Android is not billed at all and Google is working on replacement of SDK with new version that will follow the new pricing model.

This fact is mentioned on the following page:

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/product-changes/

> **Mobile SDKs for Places**
>
> Google is currently preparing new versions of the Places SDK for Android, and the Places SDK for iOS. The following section describes the changes and explains how they will affect you.
>
> - A new Places SDK for Android will be made available as a standalone library, and will no longer be available through Google Play services; This version will not be backward-compatible with the current SDK
> - A new Places SDK for iOS will be made available
>
> It's worth noting that several Places SDK features will be updated to reflect overall Places API changes, affecting both mobile platforms:
>
> - Places Details (Android, iOS) request will have a new fields parameter.
> - **Autocomplete billing will be session-based.**
>
> In the coming months we will share more details including a timeline and appropriate lead time to migrate to the new SDK versions. These new versions will replace the current SDK versions. The current SDKs will be deprecated and will follow appropriate deprecation timelines.

As you can see the new version of SDK will use autocomplete per session, so the prices can be found in **Autocomplete requests, per session** section of the pricing sheet.

I hope this clarifies your doubt.